# Asymptotic expansion of $U(j+a,2j+1,z)$ for $j \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $j \to \infty$

Tags: asymptotics, hypergeometric-function

I would like to know asymptotic expansion (at least first few terms) for the following special case of Tricomi confluent hypergeometric function:

$$f_j(a,z)=U(j+a,2j+1,z)$$ for $j \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $j \to \infty$.

In this $a$ and $z$ are complex numbers, but $z$ is most likely pure imaginary.

There's actually not a lot of good definitions for this function in the case of its second parameter being an integer.

I only found one definition (13.2.9) at https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2, but I'm not sure how to get the desired asymptotic expansion from it.

This question originates from a quantum mechanics scattering problem I'm solving.

Comment: You can use http://dlmf.nist.gov/33.2.E8, http://dlmf.nist.gov/33.2.E11 and http://dlmf.nist.gov/33.5.iv

Comment: Let $\operatorname {Re} z \geq 0$. We can use the identity $U(a, b, z) = z^{1 - b} U(a - b + 1, 2 - b, z)$ and write $U$ on the rhs as an integral over $\gamma = (\infty - i, t_0 - i, t_0 + i, \infty + i)$ with $t_0 = -1/2$, asymptotically equivalent to the integral over $[t_0 - i \epsilon, t_0 + i \epsilon]$. Thus
$$f_j(a, z) =
\frac {z^{-2 j} \Gamma(j - a + 1)} {2 \pi i} \int_\gamma
 (-t)^{a - 1} (t + 1)^{-a} e^{-z t} e^{j (-\ln(-t) - \ln(t + 1))} dt \sim \\
\frac {z^{-2 j} \Gamma(j - a + 1)} {2 \pi i} 2 i e^{z/2}
 \int_{\mathbb R} e^{j (2 \ln 2 - 4 \xi^2)} d\xi.$$